# Can I create a header file in Ideone?

Tags: online-compilation

Ideone's [FAQ](https://ideone.com/faq) page doesn't cover that, I think. I am able to write my code in main.c or main.cpp respectively, but would I be able to create a header file, and include it to my `main()`?

For example, Overleaf for [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) allows me to have multiple files.

Comment: Why do you need to do this on ideone? It is just for trying stuff out - just cut'n'paste the header - as the preprocessor would do.

Comment: AFAIK you can't. But there's [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox).

Comment: EdHeal well I was trying to answer this question..So yes just to try out. @πάνταῥεῖ cool, didn't know that. I posted an answer based on your comment, but if you feel like posting one, let me know and I will delete it at once.

Comment: We are not the support forum of ideone. Why don't you are on their site?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wandbox is so good, danke for your suggestion! :) TooHonestForThisSite, I will keep your tip for next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't strictly need to create a header to reproduce a piece of code that uses a header. You can perform the preprocessing manually, and copy the contents of the header in place of the include.

However, to demonstrate the behaviour of the preprocessor itself, the ability to create a header would be needed. I don't think that is possible on ideone.

---

https://wandbox.org/ appears to have proper support for multiple files.

On http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com it is technically possible by injecting from the command line. Not practical for long headers, for obvious reasons.

```
echo 'inline int foo(){return 42;}' > header.h && g++ main.cpp && ./a.out
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45768dedb322b520)

Comment: coliru != ideone

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ whoops, I always use coliru, and forgot that ideone wasn't the same thing. A brain fart. Answer edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put something like

```
#include "xxx.h"

int main()
{
    xxx(int yyy));
    return 0;
}
```

Into ideone.com, just remove the `#include` bit, and cut'n'paste the file into location of the `#include`

i.e.

```
/* xxx.h header file */

void xxx(int);
#define YYY_DEFAULT 1

/* end of header file */
int main()
{
    xxx(int yyy));
    return 0;
}
```

This is exactly what the preprocessor effectively does.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create a header file in Ideone?

No.

It seems that πάντα ῥεῖ is correct, about Ideone not providing this feature.

However, **[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)** does allow to include a header file, as well as source files (which could for example define the declared functions of the header files).

Example:

[image]